# Python: DataError - String or Binary data would be truncated

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm trying to insert values into my newly created table. I'm getting the following error:

```
row['Retailer'])

DataError: ('22001', '[22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. (8152) (SQLExecDirectW); [22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)')
```

I found examples with similar problems and it seems the problem involves inserting string values that have more characters than a column can accommodate.

I however tried to resolve this by increasing the size of my column but the error still appears.

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import numpy as np

"""
for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
    print(driver)
"""

#define the server name, database and login credentials
server = '#########'
database ='#########'
username='########'
password='#######'

#define connection string
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; \
                      SERVER=' + server +';\
                      DATABASE='+ database +';\
                      UID='+ username +';\
                      PWD='+ password +';')

cnxn.autocommit = True
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute(" IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.vintage_data_2') IS NOT NULL\
               DROP TABLE dbo.vintage_data_2; \
               CREATE TABLE ABC.[dbo].vintage_data_2 \
               ([ConsumerID] float,[SubscriberID] numeric(11,0), \
               [OpeningBalanceAmt] numeric(19,4),[AccountOpenedDate] varchar,\
               [RetroDate] varchar,[Retailer] varchar(30))")
cnxn.commit()

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ABC.[dbo].vintage_data_2([ConsumerID],\
          [SubscriberID],[OpeningBalanceAmt],[AccountOpenedDate],[RetroDate],\
          ,[Retailer]) \
              values (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
              row['CONSUMERID'],  
              row['SubscriberID'],
              row['OpeningBalanceAmt'], 
              row['AccountOpenedDate'], 
              row['RetroDate'], 
              row['Retailer']) 
cnxn.commit()
```

The data inside the Retailer column looks like this:

```
 print(df['Retailer'])
0      Retailer 4
1      Retailer 6
2      Retailer 3
3      Retailer 6
4      Retailer 2
5      Retailer 6
6      Retailer 2
7      Retailer 5
8      Homechoice
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the [Retailer] column that would be truncated? You've declared a couple of other columns as `varchar` and in SQL Server an unqualified `varchar` is interpreted as `varchar(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did a check in SQL Server. Works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when using an unqualified `varchar` keyword in CREATE TABLE, DECLARE, etc.. `varchar` is often (always?) interpreted as `varchar(1)` in SQL Server.